# Setting a rails session in an ajax post

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, session

Kind of a strange problem, hopefully someone can help me out.

I want to set a session in my rails controller which I hit via jquery ajax post.

Its a regular rails form which i submit via ajax

```
 $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data){

 }, 'json');
```

which hits the leads controller

```
def create
    @lead = Lead.new(params[:lead])
    @lead.save!

    if @lead.save
      session[:lead] = "#{@lead.id}"
    end

  end
```

however the session doesnt seem to be set across the ajax call.

Anyone have an ideas on this?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126721/rails-not-reloading-session-on-ajax-post

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually see create being called in your controller (did it appear in the log)?

BTW: you're calling save() twice, but this is not the problem (calling save multiple times returns true every time if the save is successful).

Comment: Yes, it is being shown in the logs, started POST "/leads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-02 21:23:24 +0000 Processing by LeadsController#create as JSON

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be because your using your localhost and not a proper domain I have heard some browsers ignore such sessions.

The other problem could be your not sending the CSRF authentication token used to stop forgery attacks, this is now a requirement for XHR requests by default and not just forms (although it may not have been with the version of rails at the time of your original post).