# CanCan user parameter always nil only ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

i'm using Cancan + Devise in my rails app:

the problem happens when i try to update Comment record, i guess the user parameter of initialize method always is coming `nil` even i'm logged:

Ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability


  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    unless user.nil?
      if user.role.name == "admin"
        can :manage, :all
      elsif user.role.name == "atendimento"
        can :manage, Comment
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Better_errors 
[image: Better Errors]

finally it raises this error.

[image]

everyone is facing this issue? 
anyone can help me?

Rails 3.2.8
Devise 2.1.0
CanCan 1.6.9
Ruby 1.9.3p385

**Edit 1**

CommentsController.rb

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController

   authorize_resource :only => [:index, :show,:new,:edit, :create,:update,:destroy,  :approve, :moderate, :disapprove]

   layout "admin"
```

**Edit 2**

Hey guys, CanCan works fine excerpt when controller receive ajax request..

Comments.js

```
 var request = $.ajax({
   url: url_to_request,
   type: "PUT",
   data: {id : id_to_send, answer : answer_to_send, question : question_to_send },
   dataType: "json"
 });
```

config/routes.rb

```
  resources :comments do
    member do
      put 'approve'
      put 'moderate'
      put 'disapprove'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please consider posting your code as text. Posting it as images is not very helpful if someone wants to try it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `user` that is nil, it is `user.role`.

You can use `user.role.try(:name)` or ensure the `role` method always returns an object that responds to `name`.

**Edit**

Cancan uses the `current_user` method on the controller. If that method returns nil, then user will be nil in your Ability file.

Make sure the Devise `before_filter` runs before your Cancan before filters (like a call to `load_and_authorize_resource`). If your user hasn't authenticated before Cancan starts trying to authorize, your user will be nil.

Comment: before this line `user ||= User.new # guest user` the variable user is nil, after it just a new User instance.. since i'm logged, the user must be my record isn't?

Comment: Nope. Undefined method name for NilClass that means user is nil

Comment: It's line 10... The name method is being called on role, not user.

Comment: If user was nil the error would be "undefined method 'role' for nil::NilClass".

Comment: @NandoSousa The before_filter you get with Devise needs to run before the Cancan before_filters otherwise `current_user` will return nil.

Comment: @LeviStanley this error occurs only when i hit controller with put/post ajax request, any ajax trick or something?

Comment: @NandoSousa This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126721/rails-not-reloading-session-on-ajax-post