# Rails don't reload session-data immediately after AJAX call but only on reloading whole page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, session

Basically, I have multiple-select box in the page. When the select box is changed, i want to put in session all id's being selected (one or more). The reason why i need something like that is following:

While creating new product user can create many variants of that product based on selected options(for example: Color and Size)(id's mentioned above).
So for example one product can have 2 variants(T-shirt in black color with size XL and green T-shirt with size L)

First of all i created POST route in products controller on which through AJAX i will send selected options:

```
resources :products do
    collection do
      post 'ajaxify_options'
    end
  end
```

**Ajax code**

```
$('#variant-options').change(function() {
    var option_values = [];

    $("#variant-options option:selected").each(function() {
      option_values.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: '/products/ajaxify_options',
      type: 'POST',
      data: ({'ids': option_values})
    });

  });
```

**ajaxify_options action**

```
def ajaxify_options (inside product controller)
    set_option_values params[:ids]
    head :ok, :content_type => 'text/html'
end
```

Here `set_option_values` is method in `ApplicationController` defined as:

```
def set_option_values option_values
    session[:option_values] = [] if session[:option_values].nil?
    session[:option_values] = option_values
end
```

with `get` method also (implemented as `helper_method` inside `ApplicationController`)

```
def get_option_values
    return [] if session[:option_values].nil?
    session[:option_values]
end
```

So now when user choose option (one or more) through `get_option_values` i can access to selected options from anywhere i need (partials for creating new product and variants).

**Main-problem:** When user select one or more options, through debugging i see that there is NO errors with ajax or server-side code everything is just fine and i can inspect values of selected options. **But rails DO NOT reload session data immediately after AJAX call BUT only when i reload whole page.**

[image]

**Side-problem:** Is everything fine with this code, i don't know why i think that I violate some Rails practices with populating session through ajax?

Similar question that i find is: [Rails not reloading session on ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126721/rails-not-reloading-session-on-ajax-post) 
I tried that solution but result is same.